# .animate not working along with .mouseenter/.mouseleave events?

Tags: css, jquery

I have a div as follows.

```
html:

<div id="leftdock"></div>

css:

#leftdock
{
    position: absolute;
    float:left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    background-color: #BADA7F;
    top: 30%;
}
```

following javascripts using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#leftdock').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
        margin-left: "-25px"
        }, 500);
    });

    $('#leftdock').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
        margin-left: "-25px"
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

But with this the animation does not work. My div margin-left is not changing with mouseenter/leave even.

Comment: Hi Apoorva, welcome to UX.se! This SE is for User Experience related questions. Your question is better suited for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may solve your problem

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#leftdock').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
        'margin-left': -25
        }, 500);
    });

    $('#leftdock').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
        'margin-left': -25
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
margin-left: "-25px"
```

to

```
marginLeft: "-25px"
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t57Xr/1)**